# How do I create a fixed duration timing loop in a VB.NET game?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a bit of a problem here: I made a version of the game 'Pong' in visual basic for a school project and just when I thought everything worked out fine I tried the game outside of Visual Studio and it turns out that all my timers are messed up, like waaaay faster than whilst running in VS. I know this has to do with the debugger attached to it because when I run it using ctrl+F5 in VS it runs at the same speed as outside of VS. Now my question is: can I make it so that the game like slows itself down to the speed of running with the debugger attached? Or do I have to edit my timers all over again to match the outside-of-VS speed?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make your timing loop independent of the debugger!

Comment: seems like a good way to do it :), but do I pull off such a thing? By running my game without debugger and changing my timers accordingly? I have no idea :s

Comment: ooh ok great thanks! :) can you post it as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a very basic example here [Creating Games With VB.NET](http://dreamincode.net/forums/topic/140697-creating-games-with-vbnet):  it's possibly not the ideal way to do it, but might get you started:

```
Private Sub GameLoop()
    timer.Start()
    Do While (Me.Created)
        startTick = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
        GameLogic()
        RenderScene()
        Application.DoEvents()
        Do While timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - startTick < interval

        Loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because of `Application.DoEvents`. Despite you pointing out it may not be the ideal way to do it, the answer does appear to endorse it.